# Tarski's schema T

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, model-theory

On Wikipedia, Tarski schema T says:

A sentence of the form "A and B" is true if and only if A is true and B is true

A sentence of the form "A or B" is true if and only if A is true or B is true

A sentence of the form "not A" is true if and only if A is false

Can Tarsi's schema T be viewed as a homomorphism? The case of a negation seems problematic?

Answer (score 2):

Let $L$ be a first-order language. Schema T can be viewed as a homomorphism from the Boolean algebra of sentences of $L$ (modulo logical equivalence) to the two-element Boolean algebra. More generally, let $W$ be a theory over $L$, and consider the Boolean algebra $A$ of sentences of $L$, modulo $W$-equivalence. Then the schema can be thought of as a homomorphism from $A$ to the two-element Boolean algebra. For more information, please see the Wikipedia article on the [Lindenbaum Algebra.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lindenbaum%E2%80%93Tarski_algebra)